# Get information of a particular X509 Certificate in C#

Tags: c#

I have a XAML application that has a combo box, which shows the list of available certificates on the system. The code for certificate selection looks like this:

```
        static List<string> GetCertificatesList()
        {
            List<string> thumbprintList = new List<string>();
            X509Store myStore = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            X509Store webHostingStore = new X509Store("WebHosting", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            myStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            webHostingStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection myCollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)myStore.Certificates;
            X509Certificate2Collection webHostingCollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)webHostingStore.Certificates;
            foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in webHostingCollection)
            {
                thumbprintList.Add("Store: WebHosting" + " | " + "Expiration: " + cert.GetExpirationDateString() + " | " + cert.Subject + " |" + cert.Thumbprint.ToString());
            }
            foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in myCollection)
            {
                thumbprintList.Add("Store: Personal" + " | " + "Expiration: " + cert.GetExpirationDateString() + " | " + cert.Subject + " |" + cert.Thumbprint.ToString());
            }
            return thumbprintList;
        }

        public static List<string> CertList = GetCertificatesList();
```

I am adding labels now as well which will contain more information about the certificate selection. Information such as the CN, Store, Expiration Date etc.

How can I retrieve the CN, Store, Expiration Date etc as well for them to be displayed in the contents of a label?

The thumbprint is then being retrieved like this.

```
public static string websiteThumbprint
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Configs.Default.App1.App1SiteInfo.websiteThumbprint))
            {
                foreach (string item in CertList)
                {
                    if (item.Contains(Configs.Default.App1.App1SiteInfo.websiteThumbprint))
                    {
                        return item;
                    }
                }
            }
                return string.Empty;
            }
        set
        {
            if (value.Contains('|'))
            {
                string[] StringParts = value.Split('|');
                Configs.Default.App1.App1SiteInfo.websiteThumbprint = StringParts[3];
            }
            else
            {
                Configs.Default.App1.App1SiteInfo.websiteThumbprint = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The `GetCertificatesList` only gets the thumbprint of the selected certificate"? You are adding more than just the thumbprint in your two `foreach` loops.

Comment: I've updated the question. Basically, I'm trying to figure out how I can these values and store them in a variable that I can use to update the contents of the label.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're asking is how to structure the information from the certificate so you can retrieve each individual detail at a time (instead of combining it all into a string), then you should be using a class for it. This is basic Object Oriented Programming, so it might be useful for you to look at some guides/tutorials to get familiar with this.

To get you started, I'd create a `CertificateInfo` and use that as the type in your list instead of `string`:

```cs
public class CertificateInfo
{
    public string Store { get; set; }
    public string Thumbprint { get; set; }
    public string ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}

static List<CertificateInfo> GetCertificatesList()
{
    List<CertificateInfo> certList = new List<CertificateInfo>();
    // Read certificates from the stores (removed here for brevity)...

    foreach (var cert in webHostingCollection)
    {
        certList.Add(new CertificateInfo
        {
            Store = "WebHosting",
            Thumbprint = cert.Thumbprint,
            ExpirationDate = cert.GetExpirationDateString(),
            Subject = cert.Subject
        });
    }

    foreach (var cert in myCollection)
    {
        certList.Add(new CertificateInfo
        {
            Store = "Personal",
            Thumbprint = cert.Thumbprint,
            ExpirationDate = cert.GetExpirationDateString(),
            Subject = cert.Subject
        });
    }

    return certList;
}

public static List<CertificateInfo> CertList = GetCertificatesList();
```

**Edit**:

From the comment:

> how can I then retrieve information such as `Store`, `Thumbprint` etc? For example, earlier (I've added the edit), I could do `Configs.Default.App1.App1SiteInfo.websiteThumbprint` and get the `Thumbprint`.

In that case you could do this:

```cs
// Note: I changed the property name to start with
// a capital letter as per C# naming conventions
public static string WebsiteThumbprint
{
    get
    {
        var websiteCert = GetWebsiteCertificate(
            Configs.Default.App1.App1SiteInfo.websiteThumbprint);
        return websiteCert?.Thumbprint ?? string.Empty;
    }
    set
    {
        // value should never contain '|' and always just be the thumbprint
        // Do you even need this setter?
        Configs.Default.App1.App1SiteInfo.websiteThumbprint = value;
    }
}

private static CertificateInfo GetCertificateInfo(string thumbprint)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(thumbprint)
        ? null
        : CertList.FirstOrDefault(cert =>
            cert.Thumbprint.Equals(thumbprint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

I would, however, recommend having just 1 property `WebsiteCertificate` that returns the whole `CertificateInfo` instead of a property for each piece of info (that would be double work since `CertificateInfo` already has those properties):

```
// '=>' is syntactic sugar for '{ get { return ... } }'
public static CertificateInfo WebsiteCertificate =>
    GetWebsiteCertificate(Configs.Default.App1.App1SiteInfo.websiteThumbprint);
```

Comment: I'm sorry for this beginner question but how can I then retrieve information such as `Store`, `Thumbprint` etc? For example, earlier (I've added the edit), I could do `Configs.Default.App1.App1SiteInfo.websiteThumbprint` and get the `Thumbprint`.

Comment: @Scripter0083 I've updated my answer with a response to your comment. In case some of the operators (`.?`, `??` etc.) are new to you, take a look at [C# operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/)